# Retrieve from a particular level in xml tree

Tags: linq, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml, decision-tree

I have the decision tree structure as such like the below ,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<root>
  outlook
  <item>
    sunny
    <root>
      humidity
      <item>
        high
        <leaf>no</leaf>
      </item>
      <item>
        normal
        <leaf>yes</leaf>
      </item>
    </root>
  </item>
  <item>
    overcast
  <leaf>yes</leaf>
  </item>
  <item>
    rain
    <root>
      wind
      <item>
        weak
        <leaf>yes</leaf>
      </item>
      <item>
        strong
        <leaf>no</leaf>
      </item>
    </root>
  </item>
</root>
```

I wanted a LINQ query which will display ,

```
Outlook : Sunny , Overcast , Rain
```

That is , root value plus the tree's first level of children's value. Again selecting a particular item like ,
    Sunny

It must iteratively give its successive root value and root's first level of children. That is ,

```
Humidity : High , Normal
```

And finally arrive at the decision , YES or NO.
Am working on the same but some inputs would help me further.

Comment: The structure of that XML doesn't seem to be very good. Mixed content should be used only in cases where your data is semi-structured (like text with some formatting). Don't use mixed content for fully-structured data. Can you change the structure of that XML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try the following:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
foreach (var r in doc.Descendants("root"))
{
    var values = r.Elements("item").Select(s => (s.FirstNode as XText).Value.Trim()).ToList();
    string.Concat((r.FirstNode as XText).Value.Trim(), ": ", string.Join(",", values)).Dump("decision");
}
```

This is output I get:

```
decision 
outlook: sunny,overcast,rain 

decision 
humidity: high,normal 

decision 
wind: weak,strong
```

I used LinqPad, hence the Dump method call which spits the output to the LinqPad console. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thnx alot.. but that wouldn't solve my problem. Since I pointed out as decision tree , i will not be able to arrive at the leaf or pass parameters which dynamically selects the path for traversal. Anyways your answer helped me.

Comment: If you describe what goes into your decision making a little clearer, ie. in and out, or the business logic, then I can wrap the above in a method call to return exactly what you are after. As the 'how' of the decision making was not clear I have provided you a generic way showing how the XML traversal can be implemented to help achieve your goals.